# How to summon an Angry Zombified Piglin in Minecraft Java 1.19

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a minecraft map with some of my friends and we're looking to make Zombie Piglins automatically angry upon summoning them.

I've looked into it a bit and there are a few things I've found. In versions prior to 1.19 (or at least around 1.8), the nbt tag `{Angry:100}` would allow you to make them mad.
However now the tag is split in 2: it's now `{AngerTime: *x*}`, the amount of time the entity is angry for, and the actual issue, `{AngryAt: []}`, which is a list of the UUIDs of entities it's mad at. The problem is that when spawning a zombie piglin, you can't do something like
`summon zombified_piglin ~ ~ ~ {AngerTime:100,AngryAt:@a}` or anything, you need the actual UUID of the player entity, but since this is a map I don't know what the ID is. Is this a thing I can do, or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I think you have a misconception, the nbt tag `AngryAt` does not store multiple entity UUIDs, it only stores 1. It is stored in a list because UUID's are separated into 4 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, summon a normal zombified piglin, then run the command `/data modify <piglin> AngryAt set from entity <player> UUID` to copy the player's UUID to the piglin.